# WPF TabItem Desire Binding to Only Occur When IsSelected True

Tags: wpf, binding, tabitem

The contents of one TabItem is large CPU expensive to create.  Would like to only get the content via binding for the TabItem when IsSelected = True.  Or get alternate content based on IsSelected True or False.  Giving up IsAsync = True in this case is not an option.

The XAML below works but it retrieves the content regardless if IsSeleted = False or IsSelected = True.

```
    <TabItem IsSelected="False"  Header="Expensive Content">
        <FlowDocumentReader Name="FlowDocumentPageViewer1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">
            <FlowDocumentReader.Document>
                    <Binding Path="MyGabeLib.Search.SelectedDoc.XAMLdocFlowDocument" IsAsync="True" Converter="{StaticResource flowDocumentToXamlConverter}" 
                        FallbackValue="{StaticResource DefaultFlowDoc}" Mode="OneWay"/>
            </FlowDocumentReader.Document>                                         
         </FlowDocumentReader>
    </TabItem>
```

The converter is to convert a string (serialized using XamlWriter.Save(DocFlowDocument)) back to a FlowDocument as cannot use IsAsync = True (directly) with a FlowDocument.

Binding to a property in the code behind to redirect did not work as the UI with IsAcync = True is on another thread and does not have access to IsSelected.

Was hoping to use a template with a trigger but this is as far as I got.  Not very far but it does not throw a syntax error.

```
    <TabItem IsSelected="False" Name="TabItemFlowDoc">        
        <FlowDocumentReader ...>
            <FlowDocumentReader.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>            
                </ControlTemplate>    
            </FlowDocumentReader.Template>
         </FlowDocumentReader>
```

Tried trigger directly on the TabControl and could not even get past syntax errors

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Name="TabControlView">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate>
                <FlowDocumentReader.Template>                   
                </FlowDocumentReader.Template>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.Resources>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think I have an answer.  Bind the IsSelected property and then can read the value of that property and return the real document if true or just a small place holder if false.  This post has had limited views and not comments or answers so I will leave this up a couple days and then delete the post.  It will even respond to a NotifyPropertyChanged and push fresh content when the tab is selected - since the binding is async I feared it might not push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was fetching the document text and other parameter for marking it up on a background thread.   Then on the UI thread I check the TabIndex if that tab is selected and only produce the FlowDocument if that tab is selected.  Another tab presents the first 4 thousand characters of the text so the user can quickly decide if they want to render the full highlighted documents.